# How to fix "Error watching file for changes: ECONNRESET" error on react-scripts start?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, create-react-app, econnreset

I'm running `npm start` on a CRA project and receiving this error after the application is runing for a brief period of time:

> Error watching file for changes: ECONNRESET

I have been working on this project for over a couple of months and have never seen this error before, it started happening this morning. I'm sure no one else has changed anything in the project since I'm the only one working on it, also I have contacted my company tech support to make sure there hasn't been any modifications nor upgrades to my workstation or the local file server we use. Additionally, when running `npm start` on my colleague's machine it works as expected.

This is the full error log I get in my shell:

```sh
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Error watching file for changes: ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1359:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-react-theme@0.1.0 start: `set PORT=3001 && react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-react-theme@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\luis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-30T13_50_03_616Z-debug.log
```

My codebase is quite large for this project. Basically I state manage with Redux and make REST calls using a custom Middleware.

I have read, in responses to other related issues, that I might be something with network requests. But when I had errors while using the REST API before, all I used to be met with as a Redux error saying that it expects actions to be plain objects. So, I'm not quite sure that my problem may come from a REST call.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently deleting my project and pulling it again from the remote repository did the trick for me. Still I don't know what has actually caused the issue, but I strongly believe it was something cache related.